# Consumir API com JQuery e salvar no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, api

Boa noite!
Estou tentando consumir uma API utilizando JQuery e Laravel.
Criei a rota para acessar e salvar os dados, o acesso sempre me retorna com status 0.

web.php:

```
Route::any('http://moviecom.com.br/MoviecomAPI/','MoviecomController@store')->name('movieAPI');
```

Na view coloquei o código javascript:

```
$.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'user_token': '',
                },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                url: "{{!! URL::to('http://moviecom.com.br/MoviecomAPI/') !!}}",
                data: {
                    'praca': 'JU2',
                    'data_ini': '2018-05-10',
                    'data_fim': '2018-05-20'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);

                    if(response.status == "Success") {
                        $(response.data[0].filmes).each( function(i, el) {

                            // Pegar os dados e salvar no banco
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(response.data[0]);
                    }   
                }
```

Estou utilizando o token corretamente e na documentação da api não diz nada sobre.

Comment: Tente acrescentar no pedido AJAX `contentType: "application/json"` para indicar que os dados que estão sendo enviados ao servidor são do tipo JSON e use a função `data: JSON.stringify(seusDados)` para converter os dados para uma string JSON.

Comment: ***Correção*** :  use `contentType: "application/json"` para indicar que os dados que estão sendo **recebidos** pela resposta do servidor são do tipo JSON.

Comment: Tentei acrescentar o contentType, mas ainda continua me retornando essa resposta: [object Object]{readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "Error: Aces..."}

Comment: Qual é o link para documentação dessa Api? a sua rota está errada também não é assim que faz ... !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a documentação é http://moviecom.com.br/MoviecomAPI/documentation/  Estou tentando algumas outras possíveis soluções também, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Aonde criou o seu token?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o token me enviaram e já testei em código sem o laravel, me rotorna os dados conforme a documentação, porém com o Laravel não funciona. Retornando apenas status: 0

Comment: Porque no Laravel foi feito errado.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, amigo. Se eu entendi bem, o que você quer é receber os dados da MovieCom no frontend e jogar para uma rota no backend. Se for isso mesmo, primeiramente, você criou uma rota nas Routes para a URI da API do MovieCom, quando na verdade deveria ser uma rota pro seu domínio. O correto seria fazer:

```
Route::post('<<rota dentro do seu sistema>>', 'MoviecomController@store')
```

E dentro do controlador, criar uma lógica para pegar os dados do frontend com request()->all() e jogar pro banco de dados.

Sobre seu AJAX, passe a url como segue abaixo:

```
url: 'https://moviedata.com.br/MoviecomAPI/'
```

Fora isso, você precisaria criar um outro AJAX do tipo POST para jogar as informações recebidas da MovieCom para a rota que você colocou no Route::post().

Mas já que você já está salvando os dados da API no banco, por que não puxa logo os dados da API no backend (usando cURL ou file_get_contents)?